# In kubernetes configmap, how to write a well-indented json using multiple lines

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to save a json value in a configmap data. The json string stored in configmap should be in a single line, and not span across multiple lines. However, I want the json to be readable, so in the yaml file I want to write it well-indented. k8s is unexpectedly preserving the newlines when I indent the json.

In the example below, I want to write the yaml key-value similar to `sell.json`, and not `buy.json`.
I am using `>-` to chop off newlines. Should I use something else?

The yaml file `transactions.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: transactions
  namespace: default
data:
  buy.json: >-
    [
    {
    "quanitity": 10,
    "price": 100,
    "name": "apple"
    },
    {
    "quanitity": 20,
    "price": 200,
    "name": "banana"
    }
    ]
  sell.json: >-
    [
      {
        "quanitity": 8,
        "price": 105,
        "name": "apple"
      },
      {
        "quanitity": 20,
        "price": 204,
        "name": "banana"
      }
    ]
```

`$ kubectl apply -f transactions.yaml`

`$ kubectl get cm transactions`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  buy.json: '[ { "quanitity": 10, "price": 100, "name": "apple" }, { "quanitity":
    20, "price": 200, "name": "banana" } ]'
  sell.json: |-
    [
      {
        "quanitity": 8,
        "price": 105,
        "name": "apple"
      },
      {
        "quanitity": 20,
        "price": 204,
        "name": "banana"
      }
    ]
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"buy.json":"[ { \"quanitity\": 10, \"price\": 100, \"name\": \"apple\" }, { \"quanitity\": 20, \"price\": 200, \"name\": \"banana\" } ]","sell.json":"[\n  {\n    \"quanitity\": 8,\n    \"price\": 105,\n    \"name\": \"apple\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"quanitity\": 20,\n    \"price\": 204,\n    \"name\": \"banana\"\n  }\n]"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"transactions","namespace":"default"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-12-28T05:35:04Z"
  name: transactions
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "36208966"
  uid: fd5c02e3-cd8d-4a8e-9a96-286ef97c4a4c
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **Folded style (`>`)** here. Using the **Literal style(`|`)** will solve your problem.

```
key: |

  Line1
  Line2

  Line3
```

This style will keep the exact same structure in the resulted yaml, except cutting off the last line (the line after `Line3`).

You can have more control on chopping the last lines, by using one of the below two variations :

- keep the last lines (by using `|+`)
- strip the last lines (by using `|-`)

Comment: Literal Style would not remove the newlines. It will preserve the content as-is. Here, my intent is to remove newlines completely.

Comment: As @Arnob Saha mentioned at the moment Kubernetes has only these two styles for providing data in  configmap creation. Is there any problem in the deployment side with getting the new line in json or you just want to do it in a well intended way?